# fetching data from firebase firestore using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application where i need to get user real time location and push it into database using geoflutterfire , the code is working but i do not understand why it keeps generating multiple documents , while on the other side using the same plugin , we should use only collection reference , can any help me with this , Thank you

- Picture showing pushing data into firestore using geoflutterfire plugin ( but why it keeps
  generating new documents , i just want to solely update the same document )

[image]

- Push data into firebase firestore

```
void updateDriverLocation(){
   Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Called");
   geoFlutterFire = Geoflutterfire();
   if(latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0){
      GeoFirePoint geoFirePoint = geoFlutterFire.point(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude);
      var map = HashMap<String,Object>();
      map['name'] = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid;
      map['position'] = geoFirePoint.data;
      _firebaseFirestore.collection("Drivers").add(map);
   }
 }
```

- get data from firebase firebase

```
   void getDrivers(){
    geoFlutterFire = Geoflutterfire();
    GeoFirePoint geoFirePoint = GeoFirePoint(latitude, longitude);
    var ref = _firebaseFirestore.collection('Drivers');
    var locations = geoFlutterFire.collection(collectionRef: ref).within(center: geoFirePoint, radius: maxRadius, field: 'position');
    locations.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
       for (var documentSnapshot in documentList) {
         Map<String,Object> map = documentSnapshot.get('geopoint');
         double lat = map['latitude'] as double;
         double lon = map['longitude'] as double;
         //_list.add(LatLng(lat, lon));
         markers.add(Marker(
                    markerId: MarkerId(DateTime.now().millisecond.toString()),
                    position: LatLng(lat,lon),
                    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker
                ));
       }
    });
  }
```

- This is how i'm trying to listen to the data returned from firestore

Answer (score 2):

```
_firebaseFirestore.collection("Drivers").add(map);
```

The `.add()` method creates a new document with a random ID every time. If you want to update a specific document then you must use `update()` on a `DocumentReference`. Try the following:

```
_firebaseFirestore.collection("Drivers").doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).update(map);
```

This will update current drivers document only.

---

GeoFlutterFire has the following to specify DocID:

```
geoRef.setDoc(String id, var data, {bool merge})
```

Comment: @Taki If you use CollectionReference with add then it'll generate new document everytime. You need that when querying the drivers in the radius not when updating the location?

Comment: The link doesn't seem to be working here @Taki but can you try using DocRef when setting the location?

Comment: @Taki yes, exactly as in my answer above.

Comment: @Taki no not there, in the "Push data into firebase firestore" snippet of yours.

Comment: @Taki but I didnt' ask to update that. Keep that one ColRef. Use DocRef in place of `add()`

Comment: in your answer , can you please add how to retrieve that object from geoFlutterFire

Comment: I'm talking about fetching of data from firestore using the geoFlutterFire plugin